# mongodb update a collection depending on each user results

Tags: mongodb

I'm totally a noob in MongoDB so I have no idea if this is even possible.
I'm building a game where users can to predict the scores of the games.

I would have some users collection `[user-1, user-2, user-3...]`

Each user have to predict the games each week, I would have a collection per week where users predictions are stored, ex:

week-1 collection:

```
[
   { 
      userId: user-1,
      game1: "1:0",
      game2: "4:1",
      game3: "0:0",
      ...
   },
   { 
      userId: user-2,
      game1: "2:2",
      game2: "3:2",
      game3: "1:0",
      ...
   },
   ...
]
```

and after week-1 it's finish I would get the real results like this:
week-1 results:

```
{
   game1: "3:1",
   game2: "2:2",
   game3: "0:4",
   ...
}
```

Can I run some automatic task on MongoDB to compare the week-1 collection vs week-1 results, calculate points each user have earn and update the main points collection? is this scenario possible to achieve?

Comment: In general you would do this with a query when loading the total high score